# How to run command on windows10 through openssh?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, openssh

I have installed `OpenSSH` on a windows10. I need to connect to this server from MacOS. I am able to `ssh` to this server from the MacOS. But I can't run a windows command through ssh. Below is the error I get:

```
$ ssh user@192.168.1.1 dir
/bin/sh: dir: command not found
```

If I send a linux command it works fine:

```
$ ssh user@192.168.1.1 ls
AppData
Application Data
Contacts
Cookies
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Favorites
```

I also tried below command:

```
ssh devel@192.168.1.1 C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe -c dir
```

it doesn't run the command, instead it login to the remote windows erver.

How can I configure open ssh to allow windows command?

The OpenSSH I installed is from https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshwindows/

Comment: There seem to be several implementations of OpenSSH for Windows. Some are related to CygWin, and so would indeed try to make the Windows host support Unix commands. So which one did you install?

Comment: the OpenSSH is from https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshwindows/.

Comment: @Zhao Yi in reviews people are saying that this installer from sourceforge will wipe your `PATH` variable in Windows 10.

Comment: Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 1):

I used this code in Ubuntu 16.04 terminal to copy a file to windows + open a script. You can target a file, but not the command line per se. The files will be opened with bash.

```
scp CalculatedOutput/Opera.csv ATV@DESKTOP-CGHF9HU:
ssh -p22 -t ATV@DESKTOP-CGHF9HU "cscript RunIf.vbs"
```

You can use winexe application to target the cmd line, but it is not easy to get it right.
Remember that all processes started from ssh or winexe will run in background. If you want an interactive cmd line session winexe seems to work well(winexe1.1) on Ubuntu 16.04 & Windows, but for automatically starting a process there seem to be problems with winexe + Samba version on ubuntu.

If you want to dir you can use winexe1.1 in a compiled version here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9gxflEDwxRydDV5NHFmWXF4M2M/view
Just put it in your code folder and you can use this command to dir directly from local terminal:

```
./winexe -U ATV%password //192.xxx.xx.xxx 'cmd /C dir C:\'
```

, or this to start an interactive session:

```
./winexe -U ATV%password //192.xxx.xx.xxx "cmd.exe"
```

As for MAC, I guess you would have to stick with the openssh options ?